# Creating folds manually for K-fold cross-validation R

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am trying to make a K-fold CV regression model using K=5. I tried using the "boot" package cv.glm function, but my pc ran out of memory because the boot package always computes a LOOCV MSE next to it. So I decided to do it manually, but I ran in to the following problem. I try to divide my dataframe into 5 vectors of equal length containing a sample of 1/5 of the rownumbers of my df, but i get unexplainable lengths from the 3rd fold.

```
a <- sample((d<-1:1000), size = 100, replace = FALSE)
b <- sample((d<-1:1000), size = 100, replace = FALSE)
c <- sample((d<-1:1000), size = 100, replace = FALSE)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
head(df)

# create first fold (correct: n=20)
set.seed(5)
K1row <- sample(x = nrow(df), size = (nrow(df)/5), replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
str(K1row) # int [1:20] 21 68 90 28 11 67 50 76 88 96 ...

# create second fold (still going strong: n=20)
set.seed(5)
K2row <- sample(x = nrow(df[-K1row,]), size = ((nrow(df[-K1row,]))/4), replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
str(K2row) # int [1:20] 17 55 72 22 8 53 40 59 69 76 ...

# create third fold (this is where it goes wrong: n=21)
set.seed(5)
K3row <- sample(x = nrow(df[-c(K1row,K2row),]), size = ((nrow(df[-c(K1row,K2row),]))/3), replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
str(K3row) # int [1:21] 13 44 57 18 7 42 31 47 54 60 ...

# create fourth fold (and it gets worse: n=26)
set.seed(5)
K4row <- sample(x = nrow(df[-c(K1row,K2row,K3row),]), size = ((nrow(df[-c(K1row,K2row,K3row),]))/2), replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
str(K4row) # int [1:26] 11 35 46 14 6 33 25 37 43 5 ...
```

The vector length seems to increase from K=3. Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?! My code (and reasoning) seems logical, but the outcome says otherwise.. My Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It's because K1row and K2row have some elements in common. You are effectively sampling with replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because K1row and K2row have some elements in common. You are effectively sampling with replacement. The method below uses modulo to split up rows evenly.

```
set.seed(5)
rand <- sample(nrow(df))

K1row <- rand[rand %% 5 + 1 == 1]
K2row <- rand[rand %% 5 + 1 == 2]
K3row <- rand[rand %% 5 + 1 == 3]
K4row <- rand[rand %% 5 + 1 == 4]
K5row <- rand[rand %% 5 + 1 == 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment ddunn801! It works perfectly! Could you explain a bit more about the modulo splitting? I'm not familiar with that. And how did create the replacement part?

Comment: Modulo returns the remainder after you  divide. Ex:  17 modulo 5 means to divide 17 by 5 (which is 3, remainder 2) and return that 2. This is a  way to split any quantity into roughly equal buckets because  the modulo you use (say, 5) is how many remainders there are (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, repeat).  Your original method doesn't know which rows were selected earlier so it happens to pick the same row number multiple times. The non-replacement you requested works from that one sample, but not across each sample. If you're happy with the answer, click the checkmark so this question is marked complete.