# How to build k-fold Cross validation for random Forest

Tags: r, random-forest, cross-validation

I am an R beginner and i have to do a 5 or 10-fold cross validation in a random forest model. My problem is i have to do the cv manually and not with an package. What i want to do is: 1. Building k-folds with my training data 2. Choose my tuning parameter for example trees = c( 200, 400, 600) 3. Fit my model on k-1 folds and predict my values on the holdout set(validation set) 4. Then i want to evaluate my prediction on the holdout set and save the value.

my evaluation parameter should be AUC. I understand the theory but i have problems to do this in R. Have you an idea for my code? Thanks so much!!!

- It is a classification Problem so as an alternative is think the iris data set would work here too.
- I stuck there that i don't se how i can fit the model on k-1 folds and predict the values on each validation set. Do i set i= 1, i=2, and so on?
  This is what i have already, but it doesn't work:

training.x = iris[, 1:4]; training.y = iris[, 5];

````
training$folds = 
 sample(1:5,nrow(training), replace=TRUE)
myGrid <- expand.grid
( ntrees = c(500, 1000, 2000),
 mtry = c( 2, 4, 6, 8)
for (i in 1: 5){
newrf = randomForest(x = training.x[training$folds!=i,] , y = as.factor(training.y)
   ,tuneGrid = myGrid , importance = TRUE , do.trace = 10)  new.pr = predict(newrf, training.mt.X[training$folds==i,], id= i)
 err.vect[i] =roc.area(test, new.pr)$class
 print(paste("AUC for fold", i, ":", err.vect[i]))}```
````

Comment: When you say you "don't know how to start", neither do we. Is your data in R? Can you divide it into groups? Do you know how to subset data? Draw random numbers? Search Stack Overflow for the [many many questions about cross validation in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40425362/903061)

Comment: Yes my data is in R and i can divide it into groups. I have already a training and a test set, and i know how to run my random forest. My main problem is i don't know how i can tune my hyper parameters and how i fit a model on k-1 fold, and the predict this values on the validation set.

Comment: What' don't you know about that? If you don't know how to tune hyper-parameters in principle, I'd suggest a textbook.  [Introduction to Statistical Learning in R](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf) is standard. See pages 181-194. That explains how to tune hyperparameters with cross validation. If you understand the algorithm and are having problems implementing it, see the link in my first comment which has an example, show what you have so far (maybe on a toy data set like `mtcars`), and try to explain *where* you're stuck.

Comment: Because the algorithm is fairly simple: you need to assign folds. Do you know how to draw random numbers? How to make a new column? Then you do a for loop, for each fold. Do you know how for loops work? In the loop, subset your data, all but one fold. Is that the issue? Fit the model on the subset. I think you know how to do this, because it's the one thing you show in the question. Then see how it performs on the hold-out fold. Is this where you get stuck? etc.

Comment: When you don't show *anything* I can't tell if we need to explain every detail like adding a column and subsetting data---or if you already have that I don't know why you're not showing it. This makes the question Too Broad. If we start from scratch and show you everything, you're asking for a 10-page tutorial, not a quick answer.

Comment: You've got a good series of steps in your question. Tackle each of them 1 at a time. *1. Building k-folds with my training data*. What don't you understand about this? The link in my first question shows an example. Did you read it? Try it? What didn't work? Where are you confused? Do you know how to draw random numbers? Add a column to your data?

Comment: Yes i know how to build k-folds, but i don't know how to validate each fold as a validation set. this is my actual code but this doesn't work already.

Comment: set.seed(123)
training$folds = 
  sample(1:5,nrow(training), replace=TRUE) 
   myGrid <- expand.grid(
  ntrees = c(500, 1000, 2000),
  mtry = c( 2, 4, 6, 8))
for (j in 1: 5){
newrf = randomForest(x = training.mt.X[training$folds!=1,] , y = as.factor(training.cla.mt.y)
    ,tuneGrid = myGrid , importance = TRUE , do.trace = 10)  new.pr = predict(newrf, training.mt.X[training$folds==1,], id= i)
  err.vect[i] =roc.area(test, new.pr)$class
  print(paste("AUC for fold", i, ":", err.vect[i]))}

Comment: Great, that's exactly what Ive been asking you to put in your question. Don't bury it in the 7th comment, edit it into your question. And share some sample data too. (Or maybe just use `mtcars`, it's often easier to debug something with a little toy data set.) If we (a) see the code you've tried in your question so we can see where you are, (b) you explain in your question the *next step* where you are stuck, and (c) you give some sample data, then this becomes a good, answerable question and will be reopened. We need all 3 of those, (a), (b), and (c).

Comment: ok i have done it

Comment: You did (a). Thanks. Do you think you can do (b) next? And  then (c)?

Comment: I see you mention `iris`, but part of *an example* is using the code *on your example*. Try to solve the problem yourself on the example. And that's the code that should be shared in the question. That will help immensely with (c), because then anyone can run the same code on the same data, work on a solution, and help you with the solution. All working from the same starting place.

Comment: Also, please read over your code for typos. Your loop is `for (j in ...)`, but you use `i` not `j` inside the loop. You are also missing several line breaks. And I'd recommend something like `training$folds != j` instead of `training$folds != 1` so that the fold changes each time through the loop...

Comment: ok so i do a) and c) but i can't run the whole model on the iris data...

Comment: Really? Why not? `training.x = iris[, 1:4]; training.y = iris[, 5]; randomFroest(x = training.x, y = training.y)` works just fine for me. Do you get an error?

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding why I'm asking for all of this from you, maybe take a look at the Stack Overflow Help Center, specifically [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That should help you understand where your question needs to be to be reopened.

Comment: yes i see it, but i'm sorry better than now i am not able to do... because i really have such lack of knowledge in R. The little thins makes me trouble

Answer (score 0):

```
# Code for 10 Fold Cross Validation: Adjust variables and data frame to yours
set.seed(17)
cv.error=rep(0,9)
for (i in 1:9){
  glm.fit=(medv~poly(lstat,i),data=Boston)
  cv.error[i]=cv.glm(Boston,glm.fit,K=10)$delta[1]
}
cv.error
plot(cv.error,type="b")
```

Comment: Add some explanation to improve quality of your answer